# Automatically converting pictures to black-and-white

Tags: color, pstricks, printing

I am submitting a paper to an Elsevier journal, and they ask that "For reproduction in black-and-white, please supply black-and-white versions of the figures for printing purposes."

My figures are all pspictures, and they are done with different colors. Is there a way to automatically make them appear in black-and-white?

Comment: It would help to post a MWE.

Comment: You could redefine all the colors to be shades of gray (in xcolor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following also works for included eps images.

**RGB to CMYK**
Put the following code into your preamble if you cannot change the PostScript code yourself.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\special{ps:
/setrgbcolor { 
  1 sub neg /Y exch def 
  1 sub neg /M exch def
  1 sub neg /C exch def 
  /K 1 def
  C K lt { /K C def } if
  M K lt { /K M def } if
  Y K lt { /K Y def } if
  K 1 eq { 0 0 0 }{ % Black 0 0 0 1
    /K1 1 K sub def
    C K sub K1 div M K sub K1 div Y K sub K1 div } ifelse
  K setcmykcolor
 } def 
}}
```

or/and **RGB to GRAY**

```
\AtBeginDocument{\special{ps:
/setrgbcolor { 0.07 mul exch 0.71 mul add exch 0.21 mul add setgray } def 
}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to John Kormylo, I found a simple solution: just add these two lines at the Document preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{gray}
```

Note that this changes only the colors generated internally in the document (including pspictures). It does not change the colors of included external graphic images.